# Checking the parent element.contains unexpectedly returns false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

My task is to close the window when clicking not on it.Here is my conditional code:

```
const closingElementRef = useRef(null);

const handleClickOnDocument = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      const { target } = e;
         if (!closingElementRef.current?.contains(target)) { (1)
           closeDropDownFilter();
        }
    },
    [dropDownIsVisible],
  );

useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOnDocument);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOnDocument);
  }, [handleClickOnDocument]);

return(
<div className='wrapper' >
  <div className='closingElement' ref={closingElementRef}>
    <button clasName='disappearingButton'>I will disappear after clicking on me</button>
    <button clasName='button'>I will NOT disappear after clicking on it</button>
  </div>
</div>
)
```

The problem is that when you click on a button that disappears after the click, line (1) returns false.
I think this is due to the fact that after clicking the DOM, the button element is removed from the DOM tree and at the time of checking "contains" it is no longer there.
Tell me please in which direction to look for a solution to this problem.

Comment: I think you want - https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/

Comment: addEventListener and removeEventListener are not usually used in React.  You should consider rewriting your code the React way before debugging what you have here.